# I want to create a website for polls/survey like this http://www.poll-maker.com/

Tags: php, database, web, logic, development-environment

but did not understand

1. The concept of generating a link &
2. more importantly how they save the data in database,do they save it like id of poll & yes/no click or done with other logic.
3. what will happen to the polls which are expired? will they remain in database or somewhere else?

please help

Comment: Google. The internet is full of information on how to build dynamic websites. Don't be lazy, do some research And come back with specific problems

Comment: i know how to make it just not sure about the logic behind it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle URL you can use cURL.

But I have an easy method. You can use the concept of [Query Strings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HofYfGbmg88).

> To Create New Question

Store the new question in database.Give Each Question a unique ID.

Then After user submits the questions show him a link like:

http://do-survey.com?question=xzxsa

> To store polls

```
Get question like:

   if(isset($_GET['question']))
   {
       $question = $_GET['question'];
        // Now you have the question unique id manipulate the database using this
   }
```

Comment: thank you mishraji...by the way which is good for identify the user so he/she will not vote more than once...

Comment: You can store the ip address of client in database and match it...or if only registered user are allowed then by email..and if my answer helps you please accept it

Comment: OK.i got it,thanks & for accepting the answer ,i require 15 reputation which i have not right now.

Comment: @SangeetShukla for voting you require 15 repo accpeting an answer doesn't require any repo..just click on the tick mark below repo

Comment: i don't know how to accept the answers,i am not able to find the option...[EDIT]Ok...i just found that tick mark...you deserve it...

Answer (score 0):

this is not the place to ask such questions, but to make my answer at least remotely useful:

they're not generating a link. That link doesn't exist under the form of a file on the server. Take for example a database containing 'id' 'poll' 'var1' 'var2'.

You can make a php page that gets a param from the link, have it like mysite.com/poll?id=1

The php script will get the '1' as a param, then you SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 and you generate the contents via php with the data from the DB.

Comment: param link ?do you mean by query string?